# Is it safe to cook meat in a Sous Vide bath with the absorbent pad attached?

Tags: food-safety, freezing, beef, sous-vide

I froze a small beef joint with the intention of cooking this from frozen in a sous-vide bath. On removing the outer plastic wrap, it appears that there is a black pad used to absorb moisture from the meat frozen to the top of joint. Either due to another layer of plastic or the inherent moisture in the pack, this pad is frozen solid into the meat and I cannot easily remove it.

Is it safe to sous vide this for 24 hours or should I remove it from the meat once it has defrosted sufficiently in the bath and then repackage in a fresh pouch?

Note: this is not the same as cooking meat in an oven with the absorbent pad attached as the temperature will not melt the material.

Comment: I have no idea if it's safe to cook with that on there, but I'd expect it to take less than 5 minutes to remove if you simply pour hot water on it before you bag the meat the first time, so there wouldn't need to be a second time.

Comment: Didn't see it as it was hidden under the produce label. In future, I'll vacuum pack meat before freezing it rather than vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Two days later after eating it and I'm still here and not suffering any ill effects.

I've learned a lesson though - remove the meat from the commercial packaging if you intend to freeze and sous-vide it. That way, additions like that pad that was hiding under the produce label can be removed.

Comment: I'm not sure you'd immediately feel any effects from eating plastics or other non-edible materials; that doesn't prove it's safe.